# Simple JPG/HTML Not Showing Up in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

I'm not familiar with iPhones wants and needs, nor do I have one, but a client wants a screen cap of his site to show up when an iPhone user comes around so I created an .htaccess redirect to an iPhone specific page with this bit of code...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iPhone/
RewriteRule .* /iPhone/ [R]
```

And the html of the iPhone page...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Eatamadedia</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#858384;margin:0 auto;">
<img src="../images/iPhonePage.jpg"> 
</body>
</html>
```

The page redirects just fine, but the .jpg doesn't show up.   I can't imagine a simpler page.  Anyone know what could be preventing the image from displaying?  Does the iPhone require headers?

The site in question is http://eatamedida.com

Thank you in advance for your input.
-J

Comment: wouldn't that rewrite condition cause ../images/ requests to be infinitely redirected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're rewrite rule is causing a redirect loop for the images directory. Change it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iPhone/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule .* /iPhone/ [R]
```

In future you can use Firefox with the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) add-on to fake the iPhone user-agent and debug these kinds of issues using Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the issues is that the pic on the iPhone page [(this one)](http://eatamedida.com/images/iPhonePage.jpg) isn't really suitable for the iPhone's screen resolution. You should consider changing the pic to a 320x480px resolution one.

However, I don't really understand the need for iPhone users to see the site screenshot, anyway.

Comment: "However, I don't really understand the need for iPhone users to see the site screenshot, anyway." You dare question the clients wants? ;) The site is a flash site, from my understanding, iPhones won't display those.  So, the client asked for a redirect to a screenshot.